# CXF not work well with .Net?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap, cxf

I created a Web Service use CXF with 1.2 soap binding.

when i try to create a C# client, try to do the "Add Web Service Reference"

the java side give and warning..

so... does it mean the two part use different standard???
can we fix this? i am worring this will cause me trobule, since i need to create a project with these two technology...

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://demo.mydemo.com/}DartProxyImplService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: MustUnderstand headers: [{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action, {http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}To] are
 not understood.
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.MustUnderstandInterceptor.checkUltimateReceiverHeaders(MustUnderstandInterceptor.java:129)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.MustUnderstandInterceptor.handleMessage(MustUnderstandInterceptor.java:87)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.MustUnderstandInterceptor.handleMessage(MustUnderstandInterceptor.java:48)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:188)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:148)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

after jdmichal`s suggestion putting

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="{your.service.namespace}YourPortName">
  <jaxws:features>
    <wsa:addressing xmlns:wsa="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing"/>
  </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

there is another new warning....does anyone know what is this problem ???
how to fix it???

```
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:25 AM org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController invoke
WARNING: Can't find the request for http://localhost:8080/DFAWebServiceProxy//'s Observer
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:34 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://demo.mydemo.com/}DartProxyImplService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /DFAWebServiceProxy/DartProxy)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.URIMappingInterceptor.handleMessage(URIMappingInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:188)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:148)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:34 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils retrieveMAPs
WARNING: WS-Addressing - failed to retrieve Message Addressing Properties from context
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:34 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils retrieveMAPs
WARNING: WS-Addressing - failed to retrieve Message Addressing Properties from context
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:34 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils retrieveMAPs
WARNING: WS-Addressing - failed to retrieve Message Addressing Properties from context
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:34 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils retrieveMAPs
WARNING: WS-Addressing - failed to retrieve Message Addressing Properties from context
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:34 AM org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor$Soap12FaultOutInterceptorInternal handleMessage
INFO: class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor$Soap12FaultOutInterceptorInternalapplication/soap+xml
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:35 AM org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker invoke
SEVERE: Invocation without a binding operation.
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:35 AM org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker invoke
SEVERE: Invocation without a binding operation.
Dec 16, 2010 10:42:35 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://demo.mydemo.com/}DartProxyImplService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:60)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:188)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:148)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to enable WS-Addressing on your Java service. The error is being thrown because .NET is asserting that the server must understand a subset of WS-Addressing, and the server is not meeting that assertion.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-addressing.html

---

Round 2:

**(Please, in the future, mark a question as answered and post a new one rather than changing your original.)**

It looks like the .NET client is attempting to access an operation, but that operation is unknown / unimplemented? Try re-importing the WSDL into .NET and see if that fixes anything. Also, are you importing the WSDL hosted by CXF, or a hand-made one? You should be using the CXF-generated one, at least until you have everything else worked out.

Comment: yes.. the old exception has gone,, but a new warning comes.... i had update the question.. can you help me to have a look at it??

Comment: i launch the java web service, then enter a link in a  browser, CXF will generate the WSDL file... and in visual studio... i copy the link from the browser, use GUI to generate a client proxy

Answer (score 0):

Well, the line:

```
AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(...)
```

Is kind of key.   It's getting a GET requet, not a POST which would be required for a SOAP request.   Double check what the client is doing to make sure it's sending a proper SOAP request.